# insert data to database before running protractor e2e test

Tags: unit-testing, protractor

I have protractor e2e tests in my project, but I have a problem to insert data to the db before running the e2e test. What is the way to do it? I have java unit test that can insert the data. Is there a way to call the java unit tests from protractor?

Thanks,

Comment: You should not be solving it on the `protractor` side - this is not the right place.

Comment: OK. So what is the way to configure that specific java junit will run before protractor?

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function in your protractor configuration file:

```
// protractor.conf.js
exports.config = {
   beforeLaunch: function() {
     // You can do it here.
   }
  ...
  onPrepare: function() {
    // Or here.
  }
```

https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js#L178

You can run a java process from node with child_process. Call java from the onPrepare function: http://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html

Comment: Good idea. Is there a way to run java before specific protractor test. Lets say I have protractorTest1.js , protractorTest2.js , javaTest1.java and javaTest2.java. I want to run:
1. javaTest1
2.protractorTest1
3.javaTest2
4. protractorTest2

Thanks,